# Polynomial division - find a monic quadratic which divides 2 given polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Find a monic quadratic polynomial, $f(x)$, which divides both 
$$g(x) = 6x^3 − 21x^2 − 42x − 15$$ $$h(x) = 12x^4 + 24x^3 + 33x^2 + 30x + 9$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Find the gcd of these two polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

You have just two unknowns to determine (the polynomial $p(x)=x^2+ax+b$). Divide $g$ and $h$ by $p$ making the two respective rests to $0$ so you get the two equations you need to calculate $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Two *linear* equations...